# How to change unix epoch to TIMESTAMP in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, epoch

I have a table that I have loaded from MongoDB into a Postgres DB. One of the columns was in JSON that I parsed out. I now have a date column that is showing as a RAW date "1672690270000" and I would like to appear in ISO format "2023-01-02 20:11:10.000".

My current datestyle is postgres is ISO, MDY.

I tried to_date and to_timestamp,

```
Select TO_TIMESTAMP(startDate, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

and recieved the same error for both,

> ```
> ERROR:  value for "YYYY" in source string is out of range
> DETAIL:  Value must be in the range -2147483648 to 2147483647.
> SQL state: 22008
> ```

What does this error mean and how can I change this date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select to_char(to_timestamp('1672690270000'::bigint/1000), 
'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS');

 to_char       
---------------------
 2023/01/02 12:11:10
```

Convert string '1672690270000' seconds and then pass to `to_timestamp()` from here [DateTime functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TABLE) then format to ISO using `to_char` from here [Data formatting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html).

Comment: Thank you!!!! I spent two hours googling and you helped me in 20 min! Much appreciated!